# What does $scope.variable.SubDomainId define in angular?

Tags: angularjs

I have a variable declared inside my angular controller:

```
$scope.variable = $scope.variable.SubDomainId
```

This variable has been bounded to html page for checking some conditions and show/hide particular DOMs according to it:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12" ng-if="variable == '2'">
```

What does this variable actually mean ?

Comment: Guessing you've inherited this from someone else?

Comment: What does your question actually mean. I don't understand exactly.

Comment: @rrd Unfortunately No! :(

Comment: @Sai Sir, I did explain properly

Comment: Just tell us clearly what do you want to do?

Comment: @Mr_Perfect I did not get what this variable actually define. I was thinking this might be any in-buily angular function/property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry Guys! It was actually defined inside an inherited controller:

```
$scope.originalvariable = { SubDomainId: '2' };
$scope.variable = $scope.screenType.SubDomainId;
```

Answer (score 0):

We don't have all your code, so I'll make some assumptions. Your variable is declared in a controller (presumably), probably in a method:

```
$scope.variable = $scope.variable.SubDomainId
```

Then in your template you have this bit of code:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12" ng-if="variable == '2'">
```

This means that if 'variable' equals '2' then that div gets displayed. You possibly have other divs that have other ng-if's and variables with other values (so you can display other content based on that variable value).

Comment: Is this the correct answer to the question? If so, can you please explain me the question?

Answer (score 0):

At first, You are assigning `$scope.variable.SubDomainId` which will obviously in Object form to the same variable `$scope.variable` which will turn into String after assignment so that doesn't make any sense and secondly based on that `$scope.variable` if the value is 2 then based on your view condition `<div class="form-group col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12" ng-if="variable == '2'">` your div will be displayed in view.